# iOS app - complex UI with separation of complex data

Tags: ios, core-data, uikit, plist, core-text

I am planning on developing a data intensive application for medical guidelines, these guidelines will need updating every so often so there will be a requirement to update them myself as the developer. One option is to put the data in a plist but I find this approach quite tedious. I was thinking of using chunks of HTML and referencing the files in my application, this way they would be a lot easier to edit.

I am curious to know how the interface below has been generated or what options I have available to generate a similar interface, is HTML the best option here or native UI elements with either Core Data + Core Text or SQLite + Core Text? Bearing in mind that I want an easy way to update the data and the data must be available to the app whilst offline?

[image: SIGN app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bearing in mind that I want an easy way to update the data and the
>   data must be available to the app

I would go with plists. I think they are quite good to hold your data and to be edit by any person (non IT related person, with HTML they would have to be careful with tags). HTML files although ok, don't think it's as good as plists, since on the last one, you immediately understand the hierarchy if you structured it correctly, while on HTML is just a bunch of files. As for the view, I do think a `UITableView` with some custom `UITableViewCells` would do the trick (I find the interface a bit ugly to be honest).

Comment: Thanks for the response, really appreciate it. How would a non-techy edit the plist file? Is there an editor they can use?

Comment: You can check this out: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14363/plistedit-pro. After the person edits it, he can send you the file and you create the build. But to be honest, an update via server would be more interesting... :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with SQLLite database, which you can frequently update from your server.

I have also created a medical app and oftenly need to update the data, so I designed it on SQLLite.

I check at program startup if a new version of the DB is available and if it is I'm downloading it on the App replacing the old version.

Just keep in mind that you need to keep a record in your App about the DB version it is running and whenever you update it you need to update the db version key on your App as well.

I would also suggest to create an editable version of the SQLLite DB in case you want to allow the users to store data to it, by copying the database from the app bundle to the users documents dir.

Comment: Thanks for the response, for the UI are you using UIWebView? Is your app on the App Store?

Comment: My app is localized and available in the Greek market as it is for Greek doctors :-) I'm using UITableView's and pdf rendering for displaying the data. The pdf rendering is done with QuartzCore [you can find a sample code on Apple's website](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html)